# Bindings in NSPopUpButtonCell

Tags: cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstablecolumn, nspopupbuttoncell

I have the following class:

```
@interface QFormatRowData : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString *rowText;
@property (copy) NSString *completeAssetName;
@end
```

In the bindings inspector of NSTableColumn (inside an outline view and it contains a NSPopUpButtonCell), I binded **Content** to a array controller called FormatAs (which contains objects of class QFormatRowData) with *controller key = arrangedObjects* and *model key path = rowText*.

Then I binded **Content values** to the same "FormatAs" array controller with *controller key = arrangedObjects* and *model key path = completeAssetName*.

Then I binded **Selected Object** to a tree controller called "dstAssetTreeController" with *Controller key = arrangedObjects* and *model key path = formatAssetName* (which is a member in the treecontroller's class).

Now I want that the pop up button cell shows options as rowText but when selected, the value of completeAssetName is allocated to formatAssetName.

That is not happening with my bindings. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- Bind Content to `arrangedObjects`, no model key path.
- Bind Content Objects (returned by `selectedObject` or `selectedObjects` in place of the corresponding content object) to `arrangedObjects`, model key path `completeAssetName`.
- Bind Content Values (displayed as the items in the `NSPopUpButtonCell`) to `arrangedObjects`, model key path `rowText`.
- Bind Selected Object to tree controller `dstAssetTreeController`, `arrangedObjects`, model key path `formatAssetName`.

Documentation: [NSPopUpButtonCell Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButtonCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSPopUpButtonCell-SW1)

**Edit:**

Xcode crashes when binding Content Objects. Workarounds:

- The cell-based `NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView` are deprecated. Convert to view-based.
- Keep trying until Xcode doesn't crash.
- Use Accessibility Inspector to confirm the Model Key Path text field.

Comment: Xcode crashes when I bind Content Objects.

Comment: I binded it with my array controller (FormatAs). In fact any changes I make in "Content Objects" section leads to a crash.

Comment: Keep trying, in a different order. Sometimes Xcode doesn't crash.

Comment: I tried in every order but XCode crashed each time. I have posted the back trace here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77966132/xcode-14-0-1-crahes-whenever-i-try-to-bind-content-objects-in-binding-inspector